# ReactJS - Maximum update depth exceeded error in PrivateRoute function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the concept of a private router to protect my application, but also to redirect in the case something hasn't been set up.

I have the error: `Maximum update depth exceeded` from the following code:

```
function PrivateRoute ({component: Component, ...rest }) {
    const stateFn = state => state.init;
    const init = useSelector(stateFn)

    const isInstalled = init.installationComplete;
    const isUserStored = localStorage.getItem('user');

    return (
        <Route
            render={props =>
                isUserStored && isInstalled ? (
                    <Component {...props} {...rest} />
                ) : !isInstalled  ? (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: "/install",
                            state: { from: props.location }
                        }}
                    />
                ) : (
                    <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
                )
            }
        />
    );
}
```

What am I doing wrong that's causing the error? And why?

Here's where I'm using the PrivateRoute:

```
class App extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const { dispatch } = this.props;

        dispatch(initActions.loadInit());

        history.listen((location, action) => {
            // clear alert on location change
            dispatch(alertActions.clear());
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { alert } = this.props;
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Helmet titleTemplate="%s | Conductor" defaultTitle="Conductor"/>
                <StylesProvider injectFirst>
                    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme[0]}>
                        <ThemeProvider theme={theme[0]}>
                            {alert.message &&
                                <Alert mb={4} severity={alert.type}>{alert.message}</Alert>
                            }
                            <Router history={history}>
                                <div>
                                    <PrivateRoute component={HomePage} />
                                    <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
                                    <Route path="/install" component={InstallationPage} />
                                </div>
                            </Router>
                        </ThemeProvider>
                    </MuiThemeProvider>
                </StylesProvider>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the redirect chain.  If, at some point, those redirects reload this `PrivateRoute` with the same props then you will get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah, i do agree with @LindaPaiste, you need to show us your routes (place where you use your PrivateRoute)

Comment: @LindaPaiste I've pasted directly from the codebase, hope it helps!

Comment: done @NikitaChayka :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PrivateRoute` will render `Route` with no path defined, which means it will be reacting to '/' path. And you use `PrivateRoute` as first component in your routing, so it will handle actually everything (cause everything starts with '/', so '/login' will be handled by your '/' route), so you should do `<Route path='/' exact .../>` This **exact** property will make this route to work only exactly when url is '/'. Other option would be to move your `PrivateRoute` as a last component in your "routing table" (where you place your `<Route>` elements)